# How to push json into a nested array - angularjs

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I can make it work when hardcoding the data, like this:

```
$scope.ChatHistory=[];
$scope.ChatHistory.push({
        IsCustomer: false,
        UserText: "Please enter the category you are looking for.",
        OptionItems: [
            { OptionId: "", SortOrder: "1", OptionName: "Complaint" },
            { OptionId: "", SortOrder: "2", OptionName: "Registration" },
            { OptionId: "", SortOrder: "3", OptionName: "Enquiry" }
        ]
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="objHistory in ChatHistory track by $index"
      ng-class="{'user': objHistory.IsCustomer, 'desk': !IsCustomer}">
      {{ objHistory.UserText }}
      <p ng-repeat="opt in objHistory.OptionItems track by $index">
         {{ opt.SortOrder }} {{ opt.OptionName }}
      </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Now, I get the data from DB like this:

```
$scope.GetData = function (categoryId) {
        DataFactory.GetData(categoryId)
        .success(function (data,status) {            
            $scope.ChatHistory.push(data);
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function (data, status) {                        
        });
    }
```

//console log

```
 "{\"IsCustomer\":false,
  \"UserText\":\"\",
  \"OptionItems\":[
     {\"OptionId\":1,\"SortOrder\":1,\"OptionName\":\"Complaint\"},
     {\"OptionId\":2,\"SortOrder\":2,\"OptionName\":\"Request\"},
     {\"OptionId\":3,\"SortOrder\":3,\"OptionName\":\"Enquiry\"}
   ]
 }"
```

How to push this 'data' into the 'ChatHistory' array now. 
$scope.ChatHistory.push(data) is not working. No error, but nothing shows up in the html.

Comment: Is the scope being "applied" (i.o.w. $scope.$apply()) after your changes?

Comment: Did you declare ChatHistory as an array so you can push to it? `$scope.ChatHistory=[];`

Comment: I think scope is being applied. I checked console.log($scope.ChatHistory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your JSON object is being returned as a string. In the code that pulls data from the DB, are you returned an array at first? If so, you could run through that array and manually store each field into your own self-created JSON object, thereby ensuring that you're effectively sending and receiving a valid JSON.

If that doesn't work (this probably meaning Angular is converting the JSON to a string during the transfer), then you could simply use JSON.parse on the variable data (the output of the console log, which is the string). However, you'd have to get rid of the newlines:

```
JSON.parse("{\"IsCustomer\":false, \"UserText\":\"\", \"OptionItems\":[ {\"OptionId\":1,\"SortOrder\":1,\"OptionName\":\"Complaint\"}, {\"OptionId\":2,\"SortOrder\":2,\"OptionName\":\"Request\"}, {\"OptionId\":3,\"SortOrder\":3,\"OptionName\":\"Enquiry\"}]}")
```

which should give you your JSON object.

Comment: Thank you. ur suggestion worked, but i had to parse it twice. Only then it works or else it shows no data `$scope.ChatHistory.push(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(data)));`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you have to push the data object into ChatHistory. Just try assigning like following:

```
$scope.ChatHistory = data; // this is the data that is returned from server call.
```

Comment: That did not work. It only adds empty li's. And also, chatHistory is an array and is like a stringbuilder. Every time there is a new set of 'data' it has to be added to the existing.